# Does DST need to be manually parsed in UTC conversions with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm defining a time with `moment-timezone` to be 2015-06-05 10:00 in Greece (UTC+2 with DST = UTC+3). Then I store it in UTC for later use.

From what I see, when I use `.local` to get back the local date it's converted to UTC+2 ignoring that they are now in DST (daylight saving time) and should be UTC+3.

You can see it here:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone'),
    myTime = moment.tz('2015-06-05 10:00', 'Europe/Athens')

myTime.format()
// '2015-06-05T10:00:00+03:00'
// OK, UTC+3

myTime.utc().format()
// '2015-06-05T07:00:00+00:00'
// OK, time changed to 7:00

myTime.local().format()
// '2015-06-05T09:00:00+02:00'
// ??? Why doesn't it take on account DST?

myTime.utc().local().format()
// '2015-06-05T09:00:00+02:00'
// Should it give back the initial value? It does not.
```

From the documentation it is not clear to me if DST is considered. Am I missing something? What would it be your approach on this?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken off the top of my head, .local converts the moment to your current local time, not back to the timezone you initialized, but check the documentation.

Comment: It's not very clear in the documentation http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/ but I'm not sure of which is the correct way to have that UTC converted to a 'Europe/Athens' timezone local date-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some explanation:

```
myTime = moment.tz('2015-06-05 10:00', 'Europe/Athens')
```

This creates a `moment` object with timezone information attached to it.

```
myTime.format()
```

This will format using that timezone.

```
myTime.utc().format()
```

This converts `myTime` to UTC by removing the timezone information. *This is a destructive operation*, it changes the `myTime` object. So the timezone information is lost. It's similar to this:

```
myTime.utc();
myTime.format();
```

Continuing:

```
myTime.local().format()
```

This disables the *"is UTC"* flag of `myTime`, which means that when formatted it will format according to your own local timezone (again, this changes `myTime`).

```
myTime.tz('Europe/Athens').format()
```

*This* will return the correct timestamp for the timezone you're interested in, by adding the timezone information back to the `myTime` object.